# How do I retrieve multiple TXT records from DNS with Java?

Tags: java, dns

I have a domain with multiple TXT records. Dig shows all of them. The nameserver returns them in a non-deterministic order. Trying to retrieve these records with the `javax.naming.directory` classes only every results in the first name returned by the nameserver — sometimes it's one, sometimes another, because the order returned by the nameserver varies.

Here's a code fragment:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
DirContext dirContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attrs = dirContext.getAttributes(name, new String[] { "TXT" });
```

At this point, `attrs` only ever contains one `Attribute`. Is this expected behaviour? How can I make Java retrieve all the TXT records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my own tests, the (single) returned attribute contains both of the `TXT` records in the domain I tried:

```
Attributes attrs = dirContext.getAttributes("paypal.com", new String[] { "TXT" });
Attribute txt = attrs.get("TXT");
NamingEnumeration e = txt.getAll();
while (e.hasMore()) {
     System.out.println(e.next());
}
```

If that isn't working for you, the [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/) library would certainly allow you to obtain all of the records.

Comment: Thanks. All I can say is that this works now, it wasn't working before! Additionally, the fact that a single TXT `Attribute` is returned which _itself_ can return a `NamingEnumeration` was lost on me. That inner `NamingEnumeration` now contains an entry for each of the values of the TXT records.

Comment: @PaulA.Hoadley Yes - the "outer" `NamingEnumeration` would contain a list of each `RRTYPE` from the list supplied to the `.getAttributes()` call, and the inner enumeration one for each `RR` within that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That was completely lost on me.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar on Android where javax.naming.directory is not supported?

Comment: @GrandAdmiral On Android I've used the `dnsjava` package to get full DNS client functionality